# Windows Store Apps: How to draw a dashed line?

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

How can I draw a dashed Line in Windows Store Apps (XAML) ?

Comment: Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465048.aspx . Then search for the Pen class in MSDN which I believe has a dashed line pattern.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't mention anything about dash lines

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [StrokeDashArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.shapes.shape.strokedasharray.aspx) property.  For example, the following XAML produces the line in the image below it:

```
<Line Stroke="Red" X1="0" X2="400" Y1="0" Y2="400" 
      StrokeThickness="9" StrokeDashArray="3,5" StrokeDashCap="Round" />
```

[image]

Comment: @IvanIčin Yup, but in that case setting it to `UniformToFill` still seems to work. It does *not* scale StrokeThickness but just extends the line to fit the provided dimensions.